# Promisse Error on tests in angular2 beta13

Tags: angular

I've update to angular2 beta13 and when running unit test's I get the following error:

> Error{line: 543, sourceURL:
>   'http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js?515e45a0cf377eb121bfd453f38a79b8d69bce25',
>   stack:
>   'resolvePromise@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js?515e45a0cf377eb121bfd453f38a79b8d69bce25:543:76
>   reject@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js?515e45a0cf377eb121bfd453f38a79b8d69bce25:599:35
>   submit subject

The test pass, so this error is handled somewhere in the framework.

I managed to pin point the error to this test:

```
        it('tries to identify the new url', () => {
            (<jasmine.Spy>mockRouter.recognize).and.returnValue(Promise.reject('someReason'));

            subject();

            expect(mockRouter.recognize).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newUrl);
        });
```

I there anything I need to do in my project?

Comment: Could you give us some hints about the code that triggers this error? Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to find a test that reproduces this error.